# npm Firebase-Admin returns 502 on messaging.send() on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-ec2, firebase-admin

I am experiencing some odd behaviour while working with the npm lib *firebase-admin*.

I have a **nodejs** application with **firebase-admin-sdk** running inside a **docker**-container that is sending push-messages to firebase cloud messaging.
On my local machine everything works out fine.

But on my AWS environment i run into **502 Bad Gateway** errors. To be clear: these errors occur after sending messages to firebase, not while receiving requests from clients. So it is the outgoin gtraffic that is causing my trouble.

I thought it might be some misconfiguration of aws ec2 and thus tried to ping http://fcm.googleapis.com/ from inside the container on the amazon ec2-machine. That worked out fine. So now i am looking for some misbehaviour of the firebase sdk that i don't seem to find.

Has anyone experienced something similar or resolved the very same problem?

Comment: Possibly an issue obtaining OAuth2 tokens? See whether accounts.google.com is reachable from the container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yep it is reachable. any other guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of investigation I decided to destroy the whole ec2-instance and rebuilt it. 
That resolved the issue. Now all the requests work out.
I hope this helps anyone facing this issue since I wasted a whole bunch of time.